# Conversion of boundary to polar coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I need to convert these boundaries of the set $\Omega =${$(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: y \leq x \leq \sqrt{y}, 0 \leq y \leq 1$} into polar coordinations? What it can be?

$$\iint_{\Omega}(x^2+y^2)\ dxdy$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you draw the picture, you will see that the region looks like half a petal. The line $y=x$ is $\theta=\pi/4$ is the upper angle, and $\theta=0$ is the lowest angle. For a given $\theta$, what range of $r$ is valid? From the picture it is obvious that we go from $r=0$ up until we hit the curve $x=\sqrt{y}$, meaning $y=x^2$. Converting to polar we find this curve is $r \sin\theta = r^2 \cos^2\theta$, or equivalently $\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos^2\theta} = r$.

Thus the integral can be expressed as
$$
\int_0^{\pi/4}\int_0^{\sec\theta\tan\theta}r^2 \cdot r\,dr\,d\theta
$$
where the extra factor of $r$ is the conversion factor (Jacobian) between rectangular and polar areas.